# How to get RGB value of a pixel in WinRT

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, windows-runtime

I am trying to get the RGB value of each pixel in WinRT app. I can access an array of bytes containing `PixelData` but I don't know how to work with that so how can I extract the RGB information from the byte array?

```
var bd = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
var pd = await bd.GetPixelDataAsync();
var tempBuffer = pd.DetachPixelData();
var PixelMatrix = new byte[bd.PixelWidth, bd.PixelHeight];
// how do I get the RGB value for PixelMatrix[0,0]?
```

Comment: You need to store three values at `PixelMatrix[0, 0]` since you have an image with three bands: R, G, and B. Therefore `PixelMatrix` needs to be declared in a different way. Or you could pack the three bytes in a larger unit, not sure if you want to handle the complications of this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a RGB image, `tempBuffer[k + 0]` is the red channel, `tempBuffer[k + 1]` is the green channel, and `tempBuffer[k + 2]` is the blue channel, i.e. `tempBuffer` is a 1D array. If you were looping over all the pixels, the pseudo code for this would be:

```
for i = 0 to height - 1
    for j = 0 to width - 1
        k = (i * width + j) * 3
        r, g, b = tempBuffer[k + 0], tempBuffer[k + 1], tempBuffer[k + 2]
```

Comment: Thanks Does the same apply across other encoding methods? for example on bgra8 does the first byte contain blue the second green...

Comment: In that case you will need to multiply by 4, since you have 4 channels now. It would be better to obtain the number of channels so the above code can serve for any number of channels. Now, the second problem in this case is that BGRA is a clearly a different ordering than RGBA, so your observation regarding the channels obtained are correct. If I were you, I would do a mapping from BGRA to RGBA so the final order in your array is always the same.

Comment: Has to change code for different pixel formats. The method below can be a lot more performant because it internally uses block copying by WinRT methods. Also - this methid will need to use some sort of BinaryReader if the pixels consist of multi-byte components, for example float.

Comment: @ananthonline: Your code is meaningless when the channel ordering is different from RGB.

Comment: In case you didn't notice - I declared two pixel formats. The idea is to declare structs laid out for multiple pixel formats and use them accordingly.

Comment: It is still bad actual code, since I don't need RGBA to use floats, there is no member for alpha channel, you don't read all the channels, etc. I'm not sure why you are commenting your solution in this answer.

Comment: Tell me how you would read in pixels that consist of 1 float per component using your code, please. Your code makes the assumption that the pixel format is 1 byte per component. That's not good practice.

Comment: Did you bother reading the answer ? It is clearly mentioned as pseudo code so the person can adapt it for whatever his needs are. If there is only 1 float per component, then there is only 1 channel, is that what you are saying ? Then you replace * 3 by * number_of_channels, in your new pseudo code.

Comment: you're given a byte[]. How can you read a float from a byte[] without a BinaryReader or some such? Think first, please.

Comment: I will try once more: the answer is a /pseudo code/, such details have no importance for it.

Comment: Such details make all the difference between performant code and slow code - especially when dealing with images. Also - the OP asks for a way to read PIXEL values given a byte[]. Not for a nested for-loop which is all your "pseudocode" is really doing (given your replies to me regarding the relevance of the loop body).

Answer (score 1):

Since the Marshal class isn't available on WinRT - the most performant way to proceed would be to use a [SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safememorymappedviewhandle.aspx)  (SafeBuffer).

This method can also handle pixelformats with multi-byte components without needing to use a BinaryReader and reading it component by component (RGBA16 with 16 bits per component). Find out what the pixel format is using the decoder's [BitmapPixelFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder.bitmappixelformat.aspx) property and use the appropriately declared structure.

```
    // declare more of these appropriately laid
    // out structures for different pixel formats
    struct RGBA16
    {
        public uint R;
        public uint G;
        public uint B;
        public uint A;
    }

    struct RGBA8
    {
        public byte R;
        public byte G;
        public byte B;
        public byte A;
    }

    struct BRGA8
    {
        public byte B;
        public byte G;
        public byte R;
        public byte A;
    }
    ...

    var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(tempBuffer /* the raw byte[] */, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    try
    {
        var ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        var safeBuffer = new SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle(true /* I believe DetachPixelData returns a copy? false otherwise  */)
        safeBuffer.SetHandle(ptr);

        #if STREAM_PROCESSING
            // pixel by pixel
            int offset = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++)
            {
                var pixel = safeBuffer.Read<RGBA16>(offset);
                offset += RGB24bpp.Size;
            }
        #else
            // Read it all in at once - this makes a copy
            var pixels = new RGBA16[width * height];
            safeBuffer.ReadArray<RGBA16>(0, pixels, 0, width * height);
        #endif
    }
    finally
    {
        safeBuffer.Dispose();
        handle.Free;
    }
```

**Note**: This method can also be a replacement for any operation that requires Marshal.PtrToStructure or some such equivalent on WinRT.

Comment: Leaving this here for people who might need to read multi-byte component based pixel formats efficiently using WinRT without the Marshal class.