# How to get the size (in pixels) of a font in WinRT app?

Tags: c#, xaml, fonts, windows-store-apps, pixel

As titled, in .NET 4.5 we have a font class which can give you the Height in pixes, but how about in WinRT?

Is there any API that I can use to get the pixels it uses?

Comment: please check this link.. hope this would help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938712/how-to-get-rgb-value-of-a-pixel-in-winrt

Comment: @RummyKhan Could you point out where that question addresses font heights? I don't see it.

Comment: @RummyKhan I don't see it how is that question related to the pixels height and width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since not even the FormattedText class exists in the .NET API for Windows Store Apps my workaround is to use a TextBlock:

```
TextBlock dummyTextBlock = new TextBlock();
dummyTextBlock.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Tahoma");
dummyTextBlock.FontSize = 18;
dummyTextBlock.FontStyle = FontStyle.Normal;
dummyTextBlock.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
dummyTextBlock.Text = "X";
dummyTextBlock.Measure(new Size(0,0));
dummyTextBlock.Arrange(new Rect(0,0,0,0));
double width = dummyTextBlock.ActualWidth;
double height = dummyTextBlock.ActualHeight;
```

That gives you the height (and width) of a text how it would be displayed.

Comment: Thanks! My current approach is using UpdateLayout to calculated the Height and Width, but this is more elegant!  I wish MS could provided an API... :(