# Image warping in .NET

Tags: c#, math, image-processing, matrix, distortion

I was searching for a stretch like warp algorithm to apply in my Windows 8 store application.
I found this android (java) code below.
Most things I can port to C# but some android sdk specific things are blurry for me to port to .NET code.

For example the call too : canvas.drawBitmapMesh , is there some .NET counterpart for this?
The Matrix classes in .NET are also a bit different I think but I can figure that out I think. 
Any tips on helping converting/porting the code below to .NET are very welcome.

```
public class BitmapMesh extends GraphicsActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new SampleView(this));
    }

    private static class SampleView extends View {
        private static final int WIDTH = 20;
        private static final int HEIGHT = 20;
        private static final int COUNT = (WIDTH + 1) * (HEIGHT + 1);

        private final Bitmap mBitmap;
        private final float[] mVerts = new float[COUNT*2];
        private final float[] mOrig = new float[COUNT*2];

        private final Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
        private final Matrix mInverse = new Matrix();

        private static void setXY(float[] array, int index, float x, float y) {
            array[index*2 + 0] = x;
            array[index*2 + 1] = y;
        }

        public SampleView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setFocusable(true);

            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                                                     R.drawable.beach);

            float w = mBitmap.getWidth();
            float h = mBitmap.getHeight();
            // construct our mesh
            int index = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y <= HEIGHT; y++) {
                float fy = h * y / HEIGHT;
                for (int x = 0; x <= WIDTH; x++) {
                    float fx = w * x / WIDTH;                    
                    setXY(mVerts, index, fx, fy);
                    setXY(mOrig, index, fx, fy);
                    index += 1;
                }
            }

            mMatrix.setTranslate(10, 10);
            mMatrix.invert(mInverse);
        }

        @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(0xFFCCCCCC);

            canvas.concat(mMatrix);
            canvas.drawBitmapMesh(mBitmap, WIDTH, HEIGHT, mVerts, 0,
                                  null, 0, null);
        }

        private void warp(float cx, float cy) {
            final float K = 10000;
            float[] src = mOrig;
            float[] dst = mVerts;
            for (int i = 0; i < COUNT*2; i += 2) {
                float x = src[i+0];
                float y = src[i+1];
                float dx = cx - x;
                float dy = cy - y;
                float dd = dx*dx + dy*dy;
                float d = FloatMath.sqrt(dd);
                float pull = K / (dd + 0.000001f);

                pull /= (d + 0.000001f);
             //   android.util.Log.d("skia", "index " + i + " dist=" + d + " pull=" + pull);

                if (pull >= 1) {
                    dst[i+0] = cx;
                    dst[i+1] = cy;
                } else {
                    dst[i+0] = x + dx * pull;
                    dst[i+1] = y + dy * pull;
                }
            }
        }

        private int mLastWarpX = -9999; // don't match a touch coordinate
        private int mLastWarpY;

        @Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float[] pt = { event.getX(), event.getY() };
            mInverse.mapPoints(pt);

            int x = (int)pt[0];
            int y = (int)pt[1];
            if (mLastWarpX != x || mLastWarpY != y) {
                mLastWarpX = x;
                mLastWarpY = y;
                warp(pt[0], pt[1]);
                invalidate();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm actually not sure why this question has all the close votes. The question is specific and shows prior research on the part of the OP. As I understand it, the answer is very specific and applies to one technology and platform. Sheesh. Can someone say SO police?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent in Windows Store apps to be able to draw a texture mapped mesh (and represent image warping and distortion that way). You will have to [use Direct3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj651551.aspx) to draw the texture mapped mesh onto your page.

If you're reluctant to mix C++ and C# in your app, you have two choices.

1. [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) - these are .NET bindings to DirectX.
2. [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/) - this is an XNA-compliant, cross-platform graphics interface that uses DirectX on WinRT.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thx, and is there any way I could directly manipulate the pixels? The warp method is already doing the manipulation on the 20x20 area. Can't I just do this in the pixels array? I have found a twist algorithm that does the warp on the whole image, I only need to do it on a small part of the image where the x and y click has been done. I'm not such a math wizard :(. Can this be accomplished without the use of Matrixes and having to draw a texture mapped mesh?

Comment: If you mean accessing the pixels for direct CPU manipulation - see my other answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938712/how-to-get-rgb-value-of-a-pixel-in-winrt/13939437#13939437). However - this will be slow for large image and/or interactive manipulation. Writing a pixel shader for an image on a quad will the best (from both a time and power utilization perspective) way to go. Note that writing a pixel shader vs a textured mesh have different pros & cons (I can clarify). 
IMHO, if you're going to be doing any image processing it is best to understand this methodology.